# Python back to previous page with remembering the elements

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, exception, browser

My script scrapes the page and if there is a new element according to my requirements, it clicks the button, when there is only one element everything is perfect but problem is when it clicks the button, a new page opens. So if there are more than one element, I need to get back to previous page to continue process.

I tried `browser.back()` for sure, but when it comes back to previous page it doesn't remember the elements and gives this error as I expected: `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up` with the line `if len(css(".Total", parent=new, nowait=True)) > 0:` which is the first line, I made it to recognise the new elements.

I also tried to open a new tab/window by clicking the button but button doesn't have this feature because it is javascript. Is there a efficent way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_window_handler = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
second_window_handler = driver.window_handles[1]

# from second page
driver.switch_to.window(second_window_handler)
element_from_second = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('something')

# from first page
driver.switch_to.window(first_window_handler)
element_from_first = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('something else')
```

now you can switch between windows, and the elements will still be interactable

Comment: Thanks but It just opens a new tab, does not open the link in a new tab. `.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND,Keys.RETURN)` this worked for me. for windows change COMMAND to CONTROL.

Comment: you can do    `url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('your-link').get_attribute('href') 
`driver.get(url)`

Comment: thank you. I marked it as a accepted answer but actually it didn't worked for me because of phantomjs. sendkeys function doesn't work with phantomjs because of not being a real browser. Also there is no way to open a new tab with phantomjs, I need to find another way or I will just keep it simple by not using this method.

Answer (score 1):

As per exception

```
  selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

we came to know that whenever page loads webdriver loosing references to webelements which it holds previously.

So the best thing is always pass locators dynamically on calling predefined keywords/methods in java prospective, so that webdriver looks for that web element at that instance and perform action.

Some times we may receive same exception in looping list of web elements, because in loop due to actions webdriver may loose reference, so in loop also we need to specify locators so that it will not fail. example if i need to click on links, i will give path like this "//a["+i+"]"

Thank You,
Murali